# Custom header with $.ajax request is inconsistent, not able to fetch in C#, MVC4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, csrf

I have implemented CSRF tokens for MVC4 Web API which does $.ajax call to MVC action method. Code is as below:

Javascript:

```
    var csrfToken = $("input[name='__RequestVerificationToken']").val();
    var request = JSON.stringify({ UserId: 1, RoleId: 2 });
    var headers = {};
    if(csrfToken)
        headers["__RequestVerificationToken"] = csrfToken;
    $.ajax({
            url: "Admin/Services/SaveAccessLevelInstructions",
            headers: headers,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: request,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            });
```

Implemented ValidateJsonAntiForgeryTokenAttribute as below:

```
    public void OnAuthorization ( AuthorizationContext filterContext )
    {
        if ( filterContext == null )
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException( "filterContext" );
        }

        string serializedCookieToken = null;
        HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName];
        if ( cookie != null )
        {
            serializedCookieToken = cookie.Value;
        }

        string serializedHeaderToken = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["__RequestVerificationToken"];
        AntiForgery.Validate( serializedCookieToken, serializedHeaderToken );
    }
```

And I added the below tag in my razor view:

```
     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

This works perfectly in my local dev. environment. But same is throwing exception saying that "__RequestVerificationToken not present" when I deployed it in production. I checked the production code for code differences but its as same as in my local version.

Now, I doubt there could be some compatibility issue with setting headers in $.ajax request.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you production server has some kind of filtering mechanism that filters out “unusual” headers? First step to debug: See what the client sends (Firebug or something), and what the server actually receives (at a very low level, f.e. no MVC stuff, just a simple standalone PHP script that dumps all received headers). Btw.: Custom HTTP headers should not be named however one likes, but start with `X-` instead.

Comment: @CBroe: Thanks for posting back. This was the implementation for CSRF token provided @ http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-(csrf)-attacks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inconsistent behavior with AJAX and ViewState in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354195/inconsistent-behavior-with-ajax-and-viewstate-in-net)